# Java- I have 100 files containing ip addresses, how yo process it efficiently each file in one hour

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I am using freegeoip api to find out country name for each ip, but call limit is 15000 per hour .
How to process each file containing 15000 ips efficiently in an hour.
Is Thread.sleep work?

Comment: Yes, Thread.sleep is work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do spread them out over the hour or you want to do 15,000 then wait until you have another 15,000 calls available to you? Or, is your concern that you won't be able to make 15,000 calls in an hour and therefore won't maximize your calls? What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: @JohnC Anything either spread the one file over an hour or wait until one hour gets over and I get another 15000 calls to make

Comment: @JohnC one file of 15000 records takes 15 mins max to process, after that i am puting thread for sleep for 45 mins. Is this a good way, my concern what if thread execution interrupts and I have to start all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are taking 15 minutes to process, The rudimentary solution is to just take note of the start time. When the process is done, see how many milliseconds is left from the current time until the start time plus one hour.

```
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 // do the requests
 long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long timePassed = currentTime-startTime;
 long millisInHour = 60*60*1000;
 long timeToWait = millisInHour - timePassed;
 Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
```

Other things you could consider is Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() to fire off a file of 15,000 every hour. Better yet, use Quartz or a similar framework to schedule jobs every hour. If running on Linux, you might even schedule the program to run with 1 file every hour using cron. In this case you don't just have a Java process running all the time in the background on your machine.

Another option is to not use freegeoip.net, but use their software which is available here https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip to then run your own server or integrate the functionality into your program.